# How can I export various components from a library using react-loadable

Tags: reactjs, code-splitting, react-loadable

I want to achieve something like this:

```
Loadable({
  loader: () => import('react-bootstrap')
})
```

and then I want to export specific components inside that like Grid, Row, Col that are usually imported as follows:

```
import { Grid, Row, Col } from 'react-bootstrap'

  //OR

import Grid from 'react-bootstrap/lib/Grid'
```